# No se puede seleccionar la base de datos - wordpress con xampp

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp

Estoy intentando instalar wordpress en local (uso xampp) pero llevo varios días atascada en el error:

"No se puede seleccionar la base de datos.
Hemos podido conectar con el servidor de la base de datos (lo que significa que tu nombre de usuario y contraseña son correctos), pero no ha sido posible seleccionar la base de datos wordpress.

```
¿Estás seguro de que existe?
¿Tiene el usuario root permisos para usar la base de datos wordpress?
En algunos sistemas, el nombre de tu base de datos tiene el prefijo de tu nombre de usuario, por lo que sería algo como nombreusuario_wordpress. ¿Podría ser ese el problema?"
```

Lo que indica en las preguntas juraría que está bien pero no sé qué puede estar fallando. ¿Será el problema en el phpmyadmin?

Gracias

Comment: phpmyadmin es una ide que usualmente se usa para conectarse a mysql... tu problema esta en algun lado entre mysql y wordpress... cuando instalaste wordpress, este creo la base de datos?

Comment: No, la base de datos la creé yo. No me deja hacer la instalación de wordpress si no está bien la conexión con la base de datos.

Comment: pero wordpress te dice que se esta pudiendo conectar a la db.. pero no a las tablas que tendria que haber creado... eso, esta creado?

Comment: sí, creé una tabla dentro de la db

Comment: Ya verificaste el usuario y la contraseña, creaste la DB, que nombre le diste, verificaste que sea el mismo en el instalador de WordPress?

Comment: sí eso es, el usuario y contraseña está bien, el nombre de la base da datos es esa y tiene una tabla dentro.  Lo único que se me ocurre es que haya hecho la tabla mal no sé o que mi phpadmin usa MariaDB

Comment: no tiene que tener una tabla... wordpress genera 8 o 9 tablas... no las genero solas al instalarse? entonces se instalo mal....

Comment: no, no las genera porque da ese error antes de instalarse. También probé a sin tablas y da el mismo error.

Comment: vale, conseguí por fin instalarlo. Lo conseguí cambiando "localhost" en el servidor por la IP y puerto que me da mi phpmyadmin.